# Pgfplots: Draw angle besides coordinate line and plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Good day, I want to show in my plot angle between coordinate line and plot like this:

[image]

Сan anybody help me with it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a minimal, yet complete example, showing your plot?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Nothing special. Just a basic plot for linear function using \addplot {x}

Comment: Well, you never know, so it's always preferable with a an example starting with `\documentclass`, containing  all necessary packages, libraries, definitions etc. (but not more), the diagram itself, ending with `\end{document}`. It also lowers the barrier for those who want to help, as we can just copy-paste your code and modify it, instead of starting from scratch.